# Segregate Cisco network using ACL's

Tags: cisco, acl, ip

I am using a Cisco 1841 router and I have 2 sub interfaces configured. F0/1.10 and 1.20.

I would like to stop the devices on VLAN 10 accessing VLAN 20 and visa versa.

VLAN 10 is on 10.10.10.1 and VLAN 20 10.10.20.1

I have configured the following access control lists

```
access-list 19 deny 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 19 permit any

access-list 29 deny 10.10.20.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 29 permit any
```

And applied them to the outbound side of the sub interfaces

```
interface f0/1.10
ip access-group 29 out

interface f0/1.20
ip access-group 19 out
```

The trouble is I can still ping across the networks.

Any help greatly appreciated, full configuration is below if you need it.

Thanks,

Full config:

```
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
ip cef
!
!
ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.201 10.10.10.255
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.20.201 10.10.20.255
!
ip dhcp pool 10.10.10.0/24
 network 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 10.10.10.1 
   dns-server 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 
!
ip dhcp pool 10.10.20.0/24
   network 10.10.20.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.10.20.1 
   dns-server 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 
!
!
vpdn enable
!

!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 description Fibre WAN Interface
 no ip address
 ip broadcast-address 0.0.0.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no ip mroute-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 pppoe enable group global
 pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
 no cdp enable
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description LAN Interface
 no ip address
 ip broadcast-address 10.10.10.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat inside
 no ip mroute-cache
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 no cdp enable
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 29 out
 ip nat inside
 no cdp enable
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 10.10.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 19 out
 ip nat inside
 no cdp enable
!
interface Serial0/0/0
 no ip address
 ip broadcast-address 0.0.0.0
 shutdown
 no fair-queue
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface Dialer1
 description ADSL WAN Dialer
 ip address negotiated
 no ip unreachables
 ip mtu 1492
 ip nat outside
 encapsulation ppp
 ip tcp adjust-mss 1452
 no ip mroute-cache
 dialer pool 1
 dialer-group 1
 no cdp enable
 ppp chap hostname bne001-indigointegrated@surfdsluk
 ppp chap password 0 T57Gfc09Hjd5SQw
 ppp ipcp route default
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 10 interface Dialer1 overload
!
access-list 10 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 permit 10.10.20.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 19 deny   10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 19 permit any
access-list 20 permit 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 29 deny   10.10.20.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 29 permit any
dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
no cdp run

control-plane

line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 access-class 20 in
 login
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a **standard access list**, so only *source* addresses are referenced.  Going out of VLAN 10, for example, your source addresses are 10.10.10.0, but its access list has 10.10.20.0 which won't match and doesn't do what you think.

You need **extended access lists** to specify the destinations which is one option keeping with the access lists idea.

```
access-list 119 extended deny ip any 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 119 extended permit ip any any
access-list 129 extender deny ip any 10.10.20.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 129 extended permit ip any any
```

- Standard IP ACLs: 1 to 99 and 1300 to 1999
- Extended IP ACLs: 100 to 199 and 2000 to 2699

Another option if you need complete routing isolation between interfaces is to use **VRF-lite** if your software supports it.

Comment: VRF is the better answer, acl is a joke for this application as it scales to more routers

Comment: OP was focused on ACL with "Segregate Cisco network using ACL's", so that's what I provided, knowing that VRF would probably be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, as it happens the ACL config didn't work anyway - I could still ping between the 10.10.10.0 network and the 10.10.20.0 network. Could you provide some example config for the VRF-lite? Thanks,

Comment: @generalnetworkerror 's config should work.  Perhaps you've mistyped something?

Comment: If one uses VRF lite, which VRF does Fa0/0 go into?

Comment: @user3580480:  The ACLs you applied in the wrong direction. I intended 119 to replace 19 and 129 to replace 29 as "ip access-group <num> out". In the deny statements, "any" is the source and 10.10.x.0 are the destination.

Answer (score 2):

So, first of all - if ACLs are being asked for, ACLs should be at least referenced first. VRFs are wonderful, but quite complex if you're having problem with ACLs :)

I personally never used ACLs in 'out' direction as in early versions of IOS (11.x, 12.0, 12.1) there were a lot of exceptions, bugs and generally things you had to debug just to make sure it works as expected.

The ACLs given by 'generalnetworkerror' are correct, as using standard ACLs won't work in the scenario. I'd however apply them in the 'in' direction and get rid of the 'out' at all. So:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1.10
 ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip access-group 29 out
 ip access-group 129 in
!
interface FastEthernet0/1.20
 ip address 10.10.20.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip access-group 19 out
 ip access-group 119 in
! (for the completness sake, generalnetworkerror ACLs reproduced):
access-list 119 extended deny ip any 10.10.10.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 119 extended permit ip any any
access-list 129 extender deny ip any 10.10.20.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 129 extended permit ip any any
```

Just for good measure I'd also add:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1.10
 ip verify unicast source reachable-via rx
interface FastEthernet0/1.20
 ip verify unicast source reachable-via rx
```